# Unable to see output in PyCharm using Calendar

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to output a month's calendar in PyCharm. My code looks like

```
import calendar
month, year = 6, 2022
print(calendar.month(year, month))
```

This is the code that I am trying to run but the problem is no output comes in the Terminal and the program keeps running and has to be terminated manually. I tried the same code in the Python Console and it ran seamlessly and even gave the expected output.
I faced no problems while debugging it as well.
If I even run any other program, the terminal is giving the expected output.
I want to know, what is the reason that this program is not giving any output in the PyCharm terminal.

Comment: What are you doing? So you can run in a PyCharm console, but not on PyCharm terminal or in a generic terminal outside PyCharm? Which terminal and shell do you use? Which command do you use to execute that program? Warning: terminal may not open in the same directory as the project, and do not use `test` or such names: shell may interpret as shell command and not as your program.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it worked for me even in debug mode. Check your Run/Debug Configuration.

Outputs:

```sh
     June 2022
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
       1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Turns out it was a configuration problem indeed.